# How to Create a module with template file of only block?

Tags: magento-2.1, module, layout, full-page-cache

I am creating a module for Widget like - Top 5 Products, Product of the Day, Best rated product, Random 5 product, latest product and this will be placed on external website via/in iframe, I don't want the output to be cached by FPC/Varnish

Which can be archived by

```
<block class="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="sample:module::sampletemplate.phtml" name="sampleblock" cacheable="false" />
```

**cacheable="false"** is used

and I want only the block template **no header, footer or content area** just the module output, some thing in the image below.

[image]

#### Question : How can I create a controller with only module output, no header, footer, no css and js, no `<head>`, `<body>` tags, etc, and the output should not be cached ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page layout="empty" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="sampleblock" cacheable="false" template="Namespace_Module::sampletemplate.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: this will create empty layout with no header, footer etc.

Comment: plz give a thumbs up if its helpful.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, though empty layout do not have header footer but it does have all the CSS and Js, it also content <head>, <body> tag, I only want the output of the widget block. nothing more.